# How do I permanently remove all the sites in IE's Restricted Zone that SpyBot S&D added?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, performance, spybot-sd

On **Windows XP** I use a utility called "[Spybot Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/spybotsd/index.html)" that helps protect my system from Spyware, while also providing great tools to inspect running processes, hidden startup applications, secure file shreding etc.

Its an awesome tool except for one major issue it has that [brutally degrades performance](http://msmvps.com/blogs/donna/archive/2009/03/20/ie8-issues-if-immunization-by-spybot-s-amp-d-is-enabled.aspx) in Internet Explorer 8.

In short, the **1,000's** of sites that the tool adds to the IE "*restricted zone*" cause massive performance issues. Thus I need to remove them.

### Steps taken thus far:

- I've turned off the "resident shield" & "Tea Timer" options
- Under Immunize I've unchecked every option
- Under settings I've turned off the "autorun" option to immunize on program start
- Full Windows reboot

### Final cleanup (that won't work!):

- In IE > Tools > Internet Options > Security > Zones > Restricted > Sites... I can delete sites to my hearts content, but **all** will return on reload/reboot
- In the Registry under HKCU > Software > Microsoft > CurrentVersion > Internet Settings > ZoneMap, I've tried to delete all options in "Domains" and "EscDomains" (again, all return after a reboot)

What are the magic steps to rid myself of this list!

*side rant question to the Spybot app developers - if IE's performance tanks with this setting turned on, why is there not an easy way to disable it!*

Comment: ie's performance didn't tank with this setting for me, sounds like something else is going on

Comment: @aking1012 - unfortunately it has been proven to majorly affect the performance, more importantly I don't want to debate it ;-) I just want to remove all items from the list.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the problem was caused by the Immunize feature.

From this [Using Spybot](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial43.html#immunize) article:

> If you would like to undo the
>   immunization, you can click on the
>   Undo button, in the black box in
>   Figure 13 above, to remove this
>   protection.

[image]

If this doesn't work, my only other advice is to ask Spybot S&D for [support](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/support/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help me out... after "undoing", and before/after a clean boot I still had the restricted zone list.

Comment: Last resort is to ask for support, as I added above.